# Dtrace Oracle show high fsflush on solaris 10

Tags: oracle, central-processing-unit, dtrace

Solaris 10 - Oracle 11G in a zone

Running mpstat , i've noticed that one CPU was at 100% used every 5 seconds for 5 seconds while all other CPU were fine, in used but nicely spread.

```
1    0   0    0  1154    1 1599   20  105   34    0  7416    9  15   0  76
2   95   0  120  1590  483 1727   33  124   27    0  8069   16   6   0  78
3  128   0    0   861    9 1333   18   96   34    0  6344    9   3   0  88
4    0   0    0   115    0    0    0    0    5    0     0    0 100   0   0
...
31   32   0    0   998   14 1797   15   81   74    0  6426    7   4   0  89
```

Using dtrace and looking for sys call only

```
dtrace -n 'profile-997hz /arg0/ { @a[pid,execname,zonename] = count(); } tick-1s { printa(@a) ; clear(@a) } '

21603 sqlplus zone-oracle 59
21669 oracle  zone-oracle 69
21737 oracle  zone-oracle 111
21613 oracle  zone-oracle 180
3     fsflush global      644
0     sched   global      17913
```

This server has lots of mem (256G) and I believe the reason why I see this behavior with mpstat is because of fsflush, after some reading (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/816-0607/816-0607.pdf) it looks like that I should be able to tune: autoup & tune_t_fsflushr but i never done this before and want to make sure that this will not have any bad impact.

Also i'm not too sure about what value should be set (according to this old publication http://oreilly.com/catalog/spt2/chapter/ch04.html) it could be set very high.

To finish, while reading the Brendon Gregg / Jim Mauro Dtrace book, it seems to be normal that the sched was so high, we are using cpu-share in the zone instead to dedicate cpu for the zone, would it make a difference to use dedicated? i'm just surprise to see that the sched is so high.

Please let me know your though and also if I got it right ?

Thx for your help.